# How can we prove the triangle inequality geometrically?

Tags: complex-numbers

I know there are many algebraic ways to prove the triangle inequalities :

1. $|z_1 + z_2| \le|z_1| + |z_2| $
2. $|z_1 - z_2| \ge |z_1| - |z_2| $

I know we can prove the inequality one using the simple fact that if the two complex no. Are represented in argand plane and line seqment is joined joining them to origin then if these two segments represent adjacent sides of ||gm then its diagonal is sum of them. hence can prove 1 using fact that sum of sides of a traingle is greater than 3rd side.

But what about 2 is there a similar way to prove it ?

Comment: 2 cannot be proved, because it's false… take $z_1 = 1, z_2 = i$ then $$|z_1 - z_2| = |1-i| >0$$ but $$|z_1| - |z_2| = 1 - 1 = 0$$

Comment: Sorry that was a typo.

Comment: Do you want a standalone geometric proof of inequality 2? Because it's easy to get 2 from 1, but I guess that would qualify as algebraic?

Comment: How can we get 2 from 1 ?

Comment: $\lvert z_1\rvert = \lvert (z_1-z_2) + z_2\rvert \le \lvert z_1-z_2\rvert + \lvert z_2\rvert$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: You have a triangle with sides $z_1$ and $-z_2$ and $z_1 + (-z_2)$. Now draw the circle whose center is the endpoint of $z_1$ and which passes through the endpoint of $-z_2$ and endpoint of $z_2$.

Here I take $z_1$ and $z_2$ to be vectors because only addition and subtraction are mentioned in the problem, because of that word "endpoint" is present.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z_1, z_2, z_3$ if viewed as vectors form three sides of a triangle

$a = |z_1|; z_1 = z_3 - z_2; $

$b = |z_2|;$

$c = |z_3|; z_3 = z_1 + z_2;$

On triangle inequality says that the third side can't be longer then the sum of the two other sides:  $|z_3| = |z_1 + z_2| \le |z_1| + |z_2|$.

$c$ (wolog the longest side) $< a+b$ (equal if colinear).

The other triangle inequality says the first side can't be shorter than the difference of the two other sides: $|z_1| = |z_3 - z_2| \ge |z_3| - |z_2|$.

$a$ (wolog the shortest side) $> c-b$ (equal if colinear).

Comment: Well, just do the exact same thing you did.  Create a parallelagram.  The longer diaganal is the sum the two numbers.  The shorter diagonal is the difference of the two numbers.  The shortest distance between two points is a straight line the shorter diagonal plus the one of the adjacent is longer than that other adjacent side.

Comment: Of course, it's a proof.  The shortest distance between two points is a straight line so $|z_3| = |z_1 + z_2| < |z_1| + |z_2| = |z_3 - z_2| + |z_2|\iff |z_3| - |z_2| < |z_3-z_2| = |z_1|$.